# Logic Apps - Add Site Address from SharePoint to CRM Field

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that creates a SharePoint file using the connector and one of the input fields is Site Address.

However I cannot add this to a CRM field as the output body does not contain this field when the file is created.

[image]

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

This is because "Site Address" is an input into the SharePoint - Create file connector, not an output. How are you specifying the site address? Is it static, or coming from some action up above? Either way you should be able to just assign the same static value/dynamic tokens to the CRM connector.

Or, if it is the file location that you cared about, you can use "Path" token which will give you an url of the file location that was uploaded to.

Comment: Hi Derek, I was hoping to use the input values somewhere else in my logic app. Is it not possible to save this  value to a global variable and then reference it later on?

Comment: Also note that using "Path" token DOES NOT return complete URL of the file location it only lists the folder location.

Comment: You can use "Compose" or "Initialize variable" to save the value.

Comment: Thanks  Derek, I used 'Compose'  to create my own JSON schema containing the URL which could be referenced later on as a token.